# How big or small should a Use Case Interactor be in Clean Architecture?

Tags: domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I’m trying to figure how best to define a Use Case using Clean Architecture and DDD.  Let’s say I have an application that handles the pick, pack and shipping of a delivery.  Here is the flow:

1. User enters a deliver to populate the screen with shipping information
2. User selects line items and clicks a button to Pick
3. User enters package information(e.g. weights and dims) and clicks a button to Pack.
4. User clicks Ship button to call an external system to get shipping labels

Here are the options I’m considering for defining my Use Case Interactors:

1. Create 4 Interactor classes, one for each step listed above
2. Create 1 Interactor class with 4 methods to handle the steps listed above
3. Create 3 Interactor classes

   a. Interactor 1 would handle the Enter Delivery and Pick

   b. Interactor 2 would handle the Packing

   c. Interactor 3 would handle the Shipping

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the business rules: what are the system's valid states? In this case the system is the `DeliveryAggregate`.

- if the system is allowed to be in any of the 4 states at a given moment then you can have 4 `Interactors` or a single `Interactor` with 4 methods.
- if the system can be in only 3 states (i.e. `Picked`, `Packed` or `Shipped`) then again, 3 Interactors or only 1 but with 3 methods.

Here you can apply `Single responsibility principle` and choose separate `Interactors`.

So, in conclusion, the `Interactos` design is strongly driven by the `Aggregates` design because the `Aggregates` are the **consistency boundaries**.

Comment: If you want to look at a detailed example, I have blogged about the topic here: https://plainionist.github.io/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-UseCases/

Comment: @plainionist Your blog is great! Thank you. This is a pretty good answer to the question, I think: "The 'driving principle' for an Interactor for a Use Case is SRP, Single Responsibility Pattern."
Your series of articles on implementing Clean Architecture is very helpful and practical.

Comment: @allenjom Thx a lot! Always great to get such feedback. I hope I will find time soon to continue the series ...

Answer (score 3):

To me, an interactor embodies a use case, and a use case is embodied by an interactor.

So in the case of a use case made out of several steps, I will wonder, for each step : is that step a valid use case by its own ?

It would make sense to see `seeing shipping information` as a use case, but would it make sense to see `select line item and mark it as picked` as a use case ?

If the answer is yes, then make an associated Interactor. Otherwise, it is probably not something that is going to be specific to one business rule and not re-used in your application (business-wide), so making an Interactor for that is unnecessary. You will not want to see it pop on your screen when you browse for use cases !

Note that the result from this perspective joins the result from Constantin's answer.